# Conditional sum of TD based on TR id on hierarchical data

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to make a financial report.
The template engine (Jinja2) dynamically creates an HTML table. The table has several rows and each row has a class that tells me at which level the row belongs to, an id that tells me what's the account code, and a data-parent attribute that tells me which account code is the parent - identify the child-parent relationship.

I'm trying to sum totals: the parent equals the values from all its children. But, I'm stuck in Javascript, and after reading a ton of questions, tutorials and etc, can't seem to figure this out.

What I came up so far:
Iterate through every code-id that's in the table (I can get this data in an array from the server). For each code, go through each row. For each row, check if the code has children. If the code has children, sum the content of all of its children. If it hasn't, skips it.

The logic seems to make sense, but I'm getting zeros still, and in middle of a bunch of for loops and if statements, I'm lost on how to debug this.

Any help is appreciated.
Cheers

```js
var table = document.getElementById("incomestatement");
var ids = [3000000, 3010000, 3010100, 3010101, 3010102, 3010103]
// Array of all data-code used in the table
var length = ids.length
for (var k = 0; k < length; k++) { // For each code...

  for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i], i < row; i++) { // for each row

    var account = document.getElementById('a' & ids[k]); // finds the TR element
    var data_code = account.dataset.code; // get's the code

    var next_account = document.getElementById('a' & ids[k]).nextSibling; // find's the sibling's code
    var next_code = next_account.dataset.parent; // finds the sibling's parent code

    if (data_code == next_code) { // if the original element is the parent of the sibbling

      for (var j = 2, col; col = rows.cells[i], j < col; j++) { // for each TD

        var total = 0;
        var values = innerHTML;
        newValue = total + values;

      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.code {
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: 0px;
}

.account {
    white-space: nowrap;
 }

.a1 {
  background-color: #1111;
}

.a2 {
  text-indent: 10px;
}

.a3 {
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.a4 {
  text-indent: 30px;
}

.values {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table id="incomestatement">

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Code</td>
        <td>Account</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="a1" ,="" id="a3000000" data-code="a3000000" data-parent="a0">
        <td class="code" data-level="a1"> 3000000 </td>
        <td class="account"> Total Revenues </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="a2" ,="" id="a3010000" data-code="a3010000" data-parent="a3000000">
        <td class="code" data-level="a2"> 3010000 </td>
        <td class="account"> First Total Revenue </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="a3" ,="" id="a3010100" data-code="a3010100" data-parent="a3010000">
        <td class="code" data-level="a3"> 3010100 </td>
        <td class="account"> Second Total Revenue </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="a4" ,="" id="a3010101" data-code="a3010101" data-parent="a3010100">
        <td class="code" data-level="a4"> 3010101 </td>
        <td class="account"> Revenue 1 </td>
        <td class="values"> 5000.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 5000.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 5000.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 5000.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 5000.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 5000.0 </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="a4" ,="" id="a3010102" data-code="a3010102" data-parent="a3010100">
        <td class="code" data-level="a4"> 3010102 </td>
        <td class="account"> Revenue 2 </td>
        <td class="values"> 900.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 900.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 900.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 900.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 900.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 900.0 </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="a4" ,="" id="a3010103" data-code="a3010103" data-parent="a3010100">
        <td class="code" data-level="a4"> 3010103 </td>
        <td class="account"> Revenue 3 </td>
        <td class="values"> 100.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 100.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 100.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 100.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 100.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 100.0 </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the sum of each level values using a recursive function, like this:

```js
function makeSumForRow(row) {
    var valueCells = row.getElementsByClassName('values');
    // fill the array of data cell values with the current values
    var values = Array(valueCells.length);
    for (var j=0; j<values.length; j++) {
       values[j] = parseFloat(valueCells[j].innerText.replace(/\s/g,''));
    }
    var childRows = row.parentNode.querySelectorAll('[data-parent="'+row.id+'"]');
    if (childRows.length > 0) {
        for (var i=0; i<childRows.length; i++) {
            // recursively calculate the sum of child row values
            var nextRowValues = makeSumForRow(childRows[i]);
            for (var j=0; j<values.length; j++) {
                values[j] += nextRowValues[j];
            }
        }
        // fill the cells with the calculated sums
        for (var j=0; j<values.length; j++) {
            valueCells[j].innerHTML = values[j].toFixed(1);
        }
    }
    // return array of the current row values for the previous level of nesting
    return values;
}

// find the "main" row (with no parent row) and call the recursion for it
var mainRow= document.querySelector('tr[data-parent="a0"]');
makeSumForRow(mainRow);
```

```css
.code {
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: 0px;
}

.account {
    white-space: nowrap;
 }

.a1 {
  background-color: #1111;
}

.a2 {
  text-indent: 10px;
}

.a3 {
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.a4 {
  text-indent: 30px;
}

.values {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table id="incomestatement">

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Code</td>
        <td>Account</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="a1" ,="" id="a3000000" data-code="a3000000" data-parent="a0">
        <td class="code" data-level="a1"> 3000000 </td>
        <td class="account"> Total Revenues </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="a2" ,="" id="a3010000" data-code="a3010000" data-parent="a3000000">
        <td class="code" data-level="a2"> 3010000 </td>
        <td class="account"> First Total Revenue </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="a3" ,="" id="a3010100" data-code="a3010100" data-parent="a3010000">
        <td class="code" data-level="a3"> 3010100 </td>
        <td class="account"> Second Total Revenue </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 0.0 </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="a4" ,="" id="a3010101" data-code="a3010101" data-parent="a3010100">
        <td class="code" data-level="a4"> 3010101 </td>
        <td class="account"> Revenue 1 </td>
        <td class="values"> 5000.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 5000.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 5000.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 5000.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 5000.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 5000.0 </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="a4" ,="" id="a3010102" data-code="a3010102" data-parent="a3010100">
        <td class="code" data-level="a4"> 3010102 </td>
        <td class="account"> Revenue 2 </td>
        <td class="values"> 900.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 900.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 900.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 900.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 900.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 900.0 </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="a4" ,="" id="a3010103" data-code="a3010103" data-parent="a3010100">
        <td class="code" data-level="a4"> 3010103 </td>
        <td class="account"> Revenue 3 </td>
        <td class="values"> 100.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 100.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 100.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 100.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 100.0 </td>
        <td class="values"> 100.0 </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. Even though it works on this specific code, it doesn’t work with more than one “a0” level account - which is the case when I add “Expenses”. I’ll take a more careful look to see what can be done in that sense. Anyways, thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe calling the function in a loop like `var mainRows= document.querySelectorAll('tr[data-parent="a0"]');
for (var i=0; i<mainRows.length; i++) makeSumForRow(mainRows[i]);` instead of the last two lines of my example would fix this issue?

Comment: Perfect, nailed it, thanks a lot. For educational purposes, would you mind sharing your rational behind structuring the code the way you did (which worked very well), vs the logic that I was trying to implement? Any red lights on the first approach? Cheers